# AngularJS Scroll to element prevent browser from jumping

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-routing

I've written an app that has a list of blocks.

Each block contains links to other blocks.
When a link to a block is clicked e.g #/home/page-19, the page animates down/up depending on current position.

This all currently works but when the anchor is clicked and the route updates, the browser jumps to the top and then animates down, I need it to animate from its current position.

I've written a directive that adds preventDefault to all anchors.

See JS fiddle below.
http://jsfiddle.net/ygNWF/10/

Stripped down code:

**HTML:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appController">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="home-template">
       <div class="page" id="page-17" >
              <div class="page-inner" ng-style="style()" resize><a href="#/home/page-18">Page 18</a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="page" id="page-18">
              <div class="page-inner" ng-style="style()" resize><a href="#/home/page-19">Page 19</a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="page" id="page-19">
              <div class="page-inner" ng-style="style()" resize><a href="#/home/page-20">Page 20</a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="page" id="page-20">
              <div class="page-inner" ng-style="style()" resize><a href="#/home/page-17">Page 17</a></div>
          </div>
    </script>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="view" ng-view scroll></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**javascript:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

/*
  Controllers
*/
app.controller( 'appController', function( $scope ) {

});
app.controller( 'routeController', function( $scope, $routeParams ) {
  //When route change, check if page has been updated and run animateScroll directive
  if(typeof $routeParams !== 'undefined' && $routeParams.page.length > 0){
    $scope.animateScroll($routeParams.page);
  }
});

/*
  Page routes
*/
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/home/:page', {
        templateUrl: 'home-template',
        controller: 'routeController'
      })

      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home/'
      });
}]);

/*
  Directives
*/
app.directive('scroll', function ($routeParams, $timeout) {
  /* 
  Scroll to element ID
  */
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      scope.animateScroll = function(page) {
        $timeout(function(){
          console.log('test');
          if(jQuery('#' + page).length == 1){
            jQuery('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop:  jQuery('#' + page).position().top
            }); 
          };
        }, 1);
      };
    }
  };
});

app.directive('resize', function ($window) {
  return function (scope, element) {
    var w = angular.element($window);

    scope.getWindowDimensions = function () {
      return { height: w.height() };
    };

    scope.$watch(scope.getWindowDimensions, function (dimensions) {
        scope.windowHeight = dimensions.height;
        scope.style = function () {
          return { 
              'min-height': scope.windowHeight + 'px'
          };
        };
    }, true);

    w.bind('resize', function () {
      scope.$apply();
    });
  }
});

app.directive('a', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

**Page layout example:**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure that scrolling should be mixed with routing. I would better do something like this:
1. use ng-click instead of href, and `href="javascript:"` (it is necessary if you support IE8)
2. use function for scrolling down that receives id of the element.

an example below

http://jsfiddle.net/naS4U/

Comment: I had this feeling. The only problem is, I need the URLS to link to the pages.

Comment: ah, ok, maybe it isn't looks great, but you can store current scroll position before redirect to new url, and after redirect move scroll to that position without delay, after that animate smooth scrolling to the selected page.

Comment: I just ran into this issue. I used href="javascript:void()" title="#idvalue"; this way you can retrieve the attribute title in old browsers as well and apply it however you like

Comment: @C.S., It is better not to use the title attribute this way, because "#idvalue" will be shown on hover state, try to use data-link attribute, or some another data-* attribute.